# launch an external installer app in Mac from Java

Tags: java, windows, macos, runtime

I´m creating a small app in Java that needs to be used in Mac and Windows from a CD.

The basic idea of this app is just to have a main menu (different for Mac and Windows) where you can select several options (install an app, view the content of the CD, view the help manual...etc) with a the logo of a company...etc.

The app to be installed is going to be different in Windows and Mac.

What I want to do is launch the external installer and once is installed, i want to launch the app.

The main problem that i have is that once I've launched the installer in a different process, the waitfor() return a valid exitvalue and continues.

I want to wait until this app is totally installed before i try to run it.

for Windows

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("    \"c:/.../ExternalAppforWin.exe\"");
```

for Mac

```
 File instFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "ExternalAppforMac.pkg")
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "open", instFolder.toString() });
 int exitVal = p.waitFor();
 if (exitVal==0)
```

...

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to check for the presence of the install window on the system rather than the executable. As far as I know, there is no system independent way to do this in Java, however with the use of powerful libraries like sun's JNA(which is supported on both windows and mac and can be found [here](http://java.net/projects/jna/downloads/directory/3.3.0)) you can do this through the appropriate OS API calls.

here is an example of what you may want to do on windows, mac calls should be similiar:

```
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;

        .
        .
        .

    //execute process
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("    \"c:/.../ExternalAppforWin.exe\"");

    //wait for return value
    int res = p.waitFor();

    //if we have a valid return code begin waiting for window to be closed
    if(res == 0)
    {
        //define a window handle variable
        WinDef.HWND windowHandle = null;
        do
        {
            //sleep a little while before polling the value
            try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(InterruptedException e){}

            //try to fetch the window by title
            windowHandle = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "<Window Title>");

            //if the handle is not null, the window is still open so sleep and then try try again
        }while(windowHandle != null && windowHandle.getPointer() != Pointer.NULL);

        //continue on with your code
    }
```

Comment: you can increase the sleep time if you feel the window state is being polled to often

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thanks for our help.  I've been researching about com.sun.jna.platform for Mac and i only have found com.sun.jna.platform.Mac.MacFileUtils with two methods: hasTrash() and moveToTrash(File[] files), so i don't think they'll help me.  Any other idea?

Comment: I see, it seems mac has deprecated all of its dynamic link libraries for interfacing with the user interface which is why jna does not have built in bindings to those functions by default, I did however, find an extension to jna that is made to bind objective c libraries and more specifically the cocoa framework. The extension is called rococoa and can be found at http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/ I have never developed on mac so i dont know the ins and outs of cocoa but it should have bindings you need

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I'll research about rococoa and i'll let you know if I get a solution.